# Blocking to be indexed

Tags: search-engine

I am wondering is there any (programming) way to block that any search engine indexes the content of a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a robots.txt file for your site.  For more info - see [this link](http://www.tconsult.com/faq/spideroff.aspx).

Comment: I accept your answer, because your link provides more info than others';) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can specify it in [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: The OP asked specifically to block *any* search engine. +1

Comment: @Pekka: not all web crawlers work for search engines.  Tnay below links to a widely used way of distinguishing the search engine indexers.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers already say, `Robots.txt` is the standard that every proper search engine adheres to. This should be enough in most cases.

If you really want try to *programmatically* block malicious bots that do not listen to robots.txt, check out **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717049/way-to-tell-bots-from-human-visitors)** I asked a few months ago on how to tell bots apart from human visitors. You may find some good starting points there.

Answer (score 2):

Most search engine bots identify themselves using a unique user agent.

You can block specific user agents using robots.txt

[Here is a list](http://www.user-agents.org/) of some user agents.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not mention programming language, I'll give my input on this as from a php perspective - there is a wordpress plugin called [bad behavior](http://www.bad-behavior.ioerror.us/), which does exactly what you are looking for, it is configurable via a code script listing an array of search agent's strings. And based on what the agent is crawling on your site, the plugin automatically checks the user-agent's string and id, or IP address and based on the array, if there's a match, it either rejects or accepts the agent.

It might be worth your while to have a peek at the code to see how is it done from a programmer's perspective of the code.

If the language is other than php, and not satisfy what you are looking for, then I apologize for posting this answer.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.