# Embeddable Google Analytics "Flair"?

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

Now that Google Analytics [**has an official API**](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html), are there any implementations of a small, minimalistic "Flair" like snippet showing a customizable selection of stats, say for example, today's and the week's visitors, and maybe a chart or two - to embed into one's own admin panels and back-end applications?

I am ideally looking for implementations based on PHP; the perfect solution would be able to run stand-alone (no big dependencies) and require just to put in the API key / login data to get started. Clean code and PHP 5 OOP would be a plus.

Comment: thanx pekka, appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GAPI sound like what you need.

GAPI (said 'g,a,p,i') is the Google Analytics PHP5 Interface.

http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

use it as follows:

```
$ga = new gapi('email@yourdomain.com','password');

$ga->requestReportData(145141242,array('browser','browserVersion'),array('pageviews','visits'));

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  echo '<strong>'.$result.'</strong><br />';
  echo 'Pageviews: ' . $result->getPageviews() . ' ';
  echo 'Visits: ' . $result->getVisits() . '<br />';
}

echo '<p>Total pageviews: ' . $ga->getPageviews() . ' total visits: ' . $ga->getVisits() . '</p>';
```

Comment: O my goodness thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! Awesim :D I wish I could give you +5

Comment: I strongly recommend anyone using this cache the data, and not output it directly into HTML. Google Analytics Data Export API is **not** a fast API, and this will significantly slow your load time.

Answer (score 2):

These are Joomla modules with php source:

- [jLabs Google Analytics Counter](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-traffic-statistics/11422):"This simple Google Analytics Counter is based on the WebResourcesDepot tutorial with the same title. And it's converted to Joomla module just for our lovely community. This counter already equipped with various color of badge styles similar with a FeedBurner's subcription counter or a Twitter Follower counter as seen in the top blog sites."
- [GAnalytics](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-traffic-statistics/9940): "GAnalytics is a complete suite which brings your google analytics data in form of charts or lists to your joomla powered web site"

The first one is based in this framework independent tutorial:

- [FeedCount-Like Google Analytics Counter](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/feedcount-like-google-analytics-counter/): "We'll be creating a dynamic FeedCount-like interface that can display your website's statistics like pageviews, visits, etc. (one or all of them) using PHP"

Which displays something like this:
[ga counter http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/956/gacnt.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/956/gacnt.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a 3rd party service called [embeddedanalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  Uses the API.  You can define charts of all sorts, geographical heat maps, and we have a simple widget giving key indicators for the month (visits, pageviews, bounce rate, etc).

This is an ideal service for someone not wanting to get into the programming aspects of the API.  Simply define your chart and embed a snippet of code where you want the chart/object to show.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not Google Analytics (I don't know of any full-featured integration libraries available for PHP yet, but you can bet they're coming), but if you're looking for something to integrate into an admin panel right now, there's always the [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) library.

But your best bet for Google Analytics might be to just build what you need from scratch using the API. Chances are you really only need a handful of charts and a couple of reports for the dashboard, and for the full in-depth detail, you're going to have to go to analytics.google.com no matter what.

Comment: Cheers @Jens didn't know about Open Web Analytics, very interesting. For the task at hand, I'm married to Google Analytics, though.