# Auto login to Google Analytics?

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, google-analytics

I have tried following similar steps as mentioned on this [Auto login to Google Analytic to impress clients](http://www.askapache.com/webmaster/login-google-analytics.html) page

```
<form id="googleanalyticslogin" action="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginBoxAuth" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Email" class="gaia le val" id="Email" size="18" value="me@gmail.com" />
<input type="password" name="Passwd" class="gaia le val" id="Passwd" size="18" value="Passw0rd" />
<input type="checkbox" name="PersistentCookie" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="rmShown" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="continue" value="http://www.google.com/analytics/home/?et=reset&amp;hl=en-US" />
<input type="hidden" name="service" value="analytics" />
<input type="hidden" name="nui" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en-US" />
<input type="hidden" name="GA3T" value="oCGYxIWWGUE" />
<input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="3Jces-nq404" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

but when I submit form I get **Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on.**

Any ideas how to sort it out? Or is there any alternative way to login?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but how about impressing clients even more by pulling Google Analytics data *into* your app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374032/embeddable-google-analytics-flair

Comment: @Pekka, thanks for the link, interesting stuff but need more features than data only

Comment: I think this is not working anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OAuth to access analytics try taking a look at this

http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

that will allow you to not only login but pull analytics straight from the site.