# How to allow users to see my Google Analytics chart data without undergoing authentication/Sign In process

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-analytics

I am using the Google Analytics Javascript library to let users view a [GeoMap](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html) of the particular page they are on. However, everytime they attempt to do so, thye have to go through an authentication process only to have my data displayed on my page. How can I find an alternative to this. I only want to embed my Analytics data through a visualized graph on my page so that all anonymous viewers can see it. This is the code where the process takes place.

```
   google.setOnLoadCallback(init); 
    /**
    * This is called once the Google Data JavaScript library has been loaded.
    * It creates a new AnalyticsService object, adds a click handler to the
    * authentication button and updates the button text depending on the status.
    */
    function init() 
    {
      myService = new google.gdata.analytics.AnalyticsService('charts_sample');

     /*
       this is essentially the line I want to replace. It anonymously 
       tries to access my viewer's account.I want to set this scope such as it 
       address the  URI of my Analytics account       
     */            

      scope = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds'; 

     /*
       if the above scope is altered to my URI then the below unnecessary login
       steps will not be required at all. This is the reason why my viewers are
       taken to their analytics page which is fundamentally non-existent.
     */   

      $("authButton").onclick = function() {
        // Test if the user is not authenticated.
       if (!google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope)) 
         {
           // Authenticate the user.
            google.accounts.user.login(scope); 
         } else 
         {
          // Log the user out.
           google.accounts.user.logout();
           getStatus();
         }
      }
     getStatus(); 
  } 

  // gets the account data and then gets the outputs of the requested query              

   function getStatus() 
   {
      getAccountFeed();
      getDataFeed();
   }


   function getAccountFeed() 
   {
      //Here agsain, I want to modify it access my account's URI  
      var myFeedUri ='https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default?max-results=50';
      myService.getAccountFeed(myFeedUri, handleAccountFeed, handleError);
  }

  function getDataFeed() 
  { 
   var myMapPopularityFeedUri = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga%3A53482361&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3Acity%2Cga%3Acountry%2Cga%3Aregion%2Cga%3Alongitude%2Cga%3Alatitude&metrics=ga%3Avisitors&start-date=2011-12-01&end-date=2011-12-25&max-results=50';

  myService.getDataFeed(myMapPopularityFeedUri, handleDataFeed, handleError);  
 }
```

Help will be appreciated a lot. Please don't be too critical. Its my first question here. Instead let me know and I will make for my amendments.

Here is a [screenshot](http://www.diigo.com/item/image/24bm9/ckmn?size=o) of what the embed looks like upon my own click, i.e, after GA has 
fetched my own data through my account. The geoMap is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: i cannot seem to find my question. could you please provide the link to that?

Comment: Its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121960/is-client-login-required-for-pulling-the-data-from-google-analytics-data-export)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best way is creating of the separate shared (public) feed (report) in Analytics.
Just feed security requires authorization login to view or receive data if the feed (report) was created under personal credentials ... independently to what version OAuth or OAuth2 is used, just if you use request to view data on the site you should use at least API key (for public reports) OR OAuth credentials for personal reports.

look this guide:
[Loading an API and Making a Request](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Samples#Google_Analytics_API)

or choose any other example from this page:
[Google Analytics: Core Reporting API Client Libraries & Sample Code (v3)](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataLibraries.html)

Use this nice tool also:
[OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Generate API key for maps:
[Google Maps API Family](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html)

Google Maps JS API tutorial:
[Google Maps JavaScript API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html)

Comment: This is my URI for getting the data,  `https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga%3A53482361&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3Acity%2Cga%3Acountry%2Cga%3Aregion%2Cga%3Alongitude%2Cga%3Alatitude&metrics=ga%3Avisitors&start-date=2011-12-01&end-date=2011-12-25&max-results=50`. Where can I set my API key here?

Comment: You mean inside feed URI? It's inadequate intention, I think.
Just API Key should to be associated with your web application.

So it is simple separate request. Before any request.

Comment: separate request? how so? Is it `analytics.data.get(GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12345&start-date=2008-10-01&end-date=2008-10-31&metrics=ga:visits,ga:bounces&key=API_KEY')` ? I have never tried this.

Comment: yes of course ... but feed (i.e same GA report) commonly be created under the influence of one of the two policies.
--
If this policy is personal(or equal) then you should use OAuth to maintain access to data, and sure, any time this will remind to user about required authorization --
or else if the policy is public then all what you need is to register your web app (it's can mean 'web page') by creating API key associated with your web app ... moreover in this case you do not necessary to use OAuth
--
for testing OAuth you can use this nice playground:
https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: API key for maps:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Maps JS API tutorial:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you. All I want to do is get my data from GA. The further task I have figured already. So one more question, can I store the response from the GET request in a variable say `myMapFeedUri` and process it for the chart as follows  `myService.getDataFeed(myMapFeedUri, handleDataFeed, handleError);` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6503/discussion-between-jbloom1704-and-swift)

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using [oAuth2](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) for the Authorization?

Comment: I haven't used it, however, from what I have researched about it, it yet requires redirection to the `Auth` page where users have to authenticate. My only concern is to display my own data in the form of the geoMap without users having to go through that process. I have included the screenshot to make it more elaborative of what I anm trying to accomplish. The authentication button `Show Popularity` at the bottom of the page plays that role of redirection and displays the geoMap present there. But that only works for me.