# Login to Google Analytics

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, forms-authentication, google-analytics

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. User opens my apps page and clicks the link: site statistics
2. My apps knows the analytics credentials, and authenticates with Google analytics, so the user does not need to provide the credentials.
3. User is redirected to Google analytics report home page.

What I have tried already:

- submitting the "fake" form from my site
- posting the form data via `Zend_Http_Client` (Curl)

The above does not work in the long run, because there are some params in Google's form generated automatically (and saved in cookie), so the user needs to authenticate himself at least once.

- started playing with `Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin`, so I have obtained very long client token and I can access the analytics data, but I still don't know how to skip the login form.

I don't want to process the analytics data myself. I just need to see it online, without manually logging in.

So, the question is, how to skip the Google Analytics form (e.g. using API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Analytics Guru, but logging the user in automatically might very well be impossible  due to security restrictions.

Logging in on server side, and proxying the data to the client, is a bad approach even if you get it working, because there's a lot of Ajax involved and stuff can break any time.

Possible alternatives that come to my mind:

- Adding guest accounts to the analytics account that are allowed to view the stats but not change anything (The user would still have to authenticate)
- Fetching data using the [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374032/embeddable-google-analytics-flair) (Obviously much more complex than what you have in mind, but as far as I can see the only method that can work completely automatically)
- Recommending the user to activate browser-side password storage - with all the downsides this includes