# How can I know if google spiders or another spiders visit my page?

Tags: php, web-crawler, user-agent

How can I know if google spiders or another spiders visit my page ?

```
<?php

if ("this is a spider") {
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: If you don't want search bots visit some of your pages, mark them in `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the value of global variable: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . For google spider, the value will look like "Googlebot*"

PHP's [get_browser](http://us.php.net/get-browser) function is also useful (check if the returned browser type is known or not- if not then most likely spider or crawler).

Comment: And *this* is why we don't like answers that just give a link... The link is down.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `USER_AGENT` header to recognize most search engine crawlers as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717049/tell-bots-apart-from-human-visitors-for-stats).

However, be warned that what you seem to be trying to do - presenting different content to crawlers than human visitors - is a technique [also known as "cloaking"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) and not well received at all by search engines.

As far as I know, with Google, this can lead to heavy penalties, up to your site vanishing from the index completely.

I would let this be, and employ legit SEO optimization instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the user agent. You can check those pages for more information :
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Agent#Robots
http://www.user-agents.org/

Then, you just have to parse the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].

Answer (score 0):

While the user agent is a decent sign that it's the googlebot, a better process would be to use what's outlined [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553) (after checking the user agent) because it's quite easy to fake a user agent.  The functions [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) and [gethostbyname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) would be good for this.