# Why is jQuery tools CDN link pointing to an ad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is the link http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js pointing to an ad?

Comment: Clear your cache and try again.

Comment: Sure that it is? I can only see a big bunch of JS there.

Comment: As of 9:47am EST 12/17/10 I see the expired domain page. Scary.

Comment: Hot damn. Whatever this turns out to be (whether it's a hijacking, a forgotten domain bill, or something else), it is a massive argument against using hosted scripts.

Comment: @Pekka: And someone is bound to come along and say "unless it's at Google", haha.

Comment: @BoltClock I was about to add that myself :)

Comment: Maybe somebody should call the owner? Although I think it won't take him long to become aware of the situation

Comment: @Pekka: He last tweeted earlier today, I've @replied to him with a heads-up.

Comment: Related tweets: http://twitter.com/#search?q=jquerytools

Comment: All my sites are screwed up, that's real stupid of me to depend on hosted script

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the [domain](http://cdn.jquerytools.org/) is expired.

As [thejh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492364/thejh) pointed out in the comments, here's a copy of the file: [jquery.tools.min.js](http://pastebin.com/2xgfSm7z)

Comment: @Pekka: Your DNS is still cached.

Comment: In that case: Why is there still JS on the site?

Comment: @SLaks you're right. Ouch, not nice for all the projects that linked there, is it?

Comment: Wow this is really bad, does anyone know where to find it? My project depends on this working

Comment: @Andreas: [whois says](http://www.whois.net/whois/jquerytools.org) it's good through 16-Dec-2011 08:36:18 UTC, suggesting it was, er, recently updated. But it looks like the registrar has taken it over.

Comment: @T.J. I think it expired and was re-registered by a squatter

Comment: @Pekka: "Created On:16-Dec-2008 08:36:18 UTC" Doesn't seem squatted.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, but somebody seems to have forgotten to pay the bill: `Status: AUTORENEWPERIOD` I think this is the provider's grace period during which a domain doesn't get unregistered, but isn't in service either.

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, I'm thinking the same.

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't see it yet, this is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Who knew the chick would eventually get into something as nerdy as frontend development?

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, but I'm not surprised! She *is* a jack of all trades.

Comment: I like to hope people recognize her on the street. "Hey, you're that girl I see instead of the website I wanted!"

Comment: @Michael the poor gal would be in grave danger of bodily harm. "Hey, the insurance you sold me ripped me off!" "The Viagra you sold me gave me a heart attack!"

Comment: Does she have a front-end library I can download for use with my tooltip?

Comment: I wanna know her name, so I can say "damnit `_______` that's not what I wanted to hear, gimme mah site" :p

Comment: @drachenstern: By convention, would she be Jenny? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny

Comment: @Piskvor hahaha, sadly no I don't think that works. But when I tell people that number all too often they look at me blank faced... sad I tell you

Answer (score 2):

[Download the lib](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html) and include it from your server