# Can anyone access the jQuery Tools from CDN?

Tags: jquery, cdn

http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/ can anyone access them? All of my scripts stopped working and they rely on the CDN and on various designs.

The site seems gone for me at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is jQuery tools CDN link pointing to an ad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471568/why-is-jquery-tools-cdn-link-pointing-to-an-ad), I think it's safe to say we can prepare for even more duplicate questions to be posted as long as it's down...

Comment: I still can't access the jquery tools or even download it.

Comment: Yeah I hope this gets resolved soon, meanwhile there is a mirror link in the other question from which you can download the library.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll have to modify all my headers.. that's real disaster. Was it my mistake to depend on hosted script, but i thought that such site is reliable :(

Comment: Not sure why people are shocked, this is the tradeoff to having it load externally, you have 0 control over the uptime.

Comment: @Jakub: Exactly. Such is life.

Comment: I'd stick with big CDNs like Google or Microsoft -- for the smallers scripts (read ones that aren't hosted by the big guys) I'd host host them on your own site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whois says that the domain jquerytools.org was updated today:

```
Last Updated On:17-Dec-2010 12:11:47 UTC
Expiration Date:16-Dec-2011 08:36:18 UTC
```

Hopefully there are only some technical problems and not a change of the domain-owner(this could happen, happens to google too a couple of years ago ^^ )

But however, a CDN has to be reachable all the time. By this I wouldn't trust anymore in jquerytools as a CDN.

Comment: I am shocked.. updating all my sites now, everything screwed up. not reliable at all :/

Comment: Even the Google CDN has had some issues in the past, but this looks worse.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to browse to the url:  http://flowplayer.org/, may be the URI is not valid anymore. Check if this is the URL you are looking for http://flowplayer.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the DOMAIN NAME `jquerytools.org` is no longer pointing to the proper CDN. It is not that the CDN is down.  Looks like the domain expired...