# PHP page views counter and google bot question

Tags: php

I have a simple php page views counter and was wondering how can I stop spiders and bots as being counted as views specifically google bot?

Comment: Not to discourage you from writing your own script, but Google Analytics is a very powerful tool if you're looking for a counter. If you're looking to create one by yourself, please ignore this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell bots apart from human visitors for stats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717049/tell-bots-apart-from-human-visitors-for-stats)

Answer (score 1):

I added this script on my site:

```
# Spiders list from http://linksku.com
$spiders = array('aspseek','abachobot','accoona','acoirobot','adsbot','alexa','alta vista','altavista','ask jeeves','baidu','crawler','croccrawler','dumbot','estyle','exabot','fast-enterprise','fast-webcrawler','francis','geonabot','gigabot','google','heise','heritrix','ibm','iccrawler','idbot','ichiro','lycos','msn','msrbot','majestic-12','metager','ng-search','nutch','omniexplorer','psbot','rambler','seosearch','scooter','scrubby','seekport','sensis','seoma','snappy','steeler','synoo','telekom','turnitinbot','voyager','wisenut','yacy','yahoo');
foreach($spiders as $spider) if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $spider) !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_CRAWLER'] = true;
    break;
}
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CRAWLER'])) $_SERVER['HTTP_CRAWLER'] = false;
```

Then you can just check the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_CRAWLER']` and block your script from counting the hit.

Comment: The spiders list is probably better off as an external include, there are at least 52 spiders that I know of. This might be a list you would want to update as and when you recognize new spiders.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method is to implement the pagecounter as image script:

```
<img src="counter.php" width="1" height="1" alt="Oh I'm just counting">
```

And mark that URL as inaccessible to spiders/crawlers via `robots.txt`, where you can either use `*` for all, or just `Googlebot` to exclude it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /counter.php
```

The alternative would be to just check for `stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT", "Googlebot")` in the script, and simply not up the counter then.