# How to create redirection only for visitors (not for search robots)

Tags: php, redirect

In the following code, I used `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to detect if visitor using browser. But this method still robots can read.

For example If I test [Website](https://zareklamy.com) on [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), then code still redirecting, Error: `302 HTTP Redirect    arrow-right https://zareklamy.com/?lang=en`.

How I can use this redirect only for visitors and not for robots?

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != '') {
    if ($http_lang == 'en-us' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-us' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-gb' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'it' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'pl') {
        header('Location: https://zareklamy.com/?lang=en-us');
        die();
    } elseif ($http_lang == 'en-gb' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-us' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-gb' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'it' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'pl') {
        header('Location: https://zareklamy.com/?lang=en-gb');
        die();
    } elseif ($http_lang == 'it' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-us' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-gb' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'it' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'pl') {
        header('Location: https://zareklamy.com/?lang=it');
        die();
    } elseif ($http_lang == 'pl' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-us' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'en-gb' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'it' && $_COOKIE['lang'] != 'pl') {
        header('Location: https://zareklamy.com/?lang=pl');
        die();
    } elseif ($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'en-us' || $_COOKIE['lang'] == 'en-gb' || $_COOKIE['lang'] == 'it' || $_COOKIE['lang'] == 'pl') {
    } else {
        header('Location: https://zareklamy.com/?lang=en-us');
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a robot requires a more detailed analysis of the user agent.

**Warning - opinion based content follows.** There are other ways to analyse user agent such as https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php.

You can use [browscap-php](https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php) to *better* detect the browser. You can then check various properties of the resulting object to increase the probability of detecting a robot.

I say *better* because it's not impossible for robots to emulate browser `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header and that way escape your detection.

```
$cache = new \Roave\DoctrineSimpleCache\SimpleCacheAdapter($doctrineFileCache); // or maybe any other PSR-16 compatible caches
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('name'); // or maybe any other PSR-3 compatible logger

$browscap = new \BrowscapPHP\Browscap($cache, $logger);
$info = $browscap->getBrowser();

if (!($info->isfake || $info->crawler)) { 
   ...
}
```

Sample browscap-php result (`$info` value) for Chrome browser follows:

```
{  
   "browser_name_regex":"\/^mozilla\\\/5\\.0 \\(.*windows nt 10\\.0.*win64. x64.*\\).*applewebkit.*\\(.*khtml.*like.*gecko.*\\).*chrome\\\/.* safari\\\/.*$\/",
   "browser_name_pattern":"mozilla\/5.0 (*windows nt 10.0*win64? x64*)*applewebkit*(*khtml*like*gecko*)*chrome\/* safari\/*",
   "parent":"Chrome Generic",
   "comment":"Chrome Generic",
   "browser":"Chrome",
   "browser_type":"Browser",
   "browser_bits":"64",
   "browser_maker":"Google Inc",
   "browser_modus":"unknown",
   "version":"0.0",
   "majorver":"0",
   "minorver":"0",
   "platform":"Win10",
   "platform_version":"10.0",
   "platform_description":"Windows 10",
   "platform_bits":"64",
   "platform_maker":"Microsoft Corporation",
   "alpha":false,
   "beta":false,
   "win16":false,
   "win32":false,
   "win64":true,
   "frames":true,
   "iframes":true,
   "tables":true,
   "cookies":true,
   "backgroundsounds":false,
   "javascript":true,
   "vbscript":false,
   "javaapplets":false,
   "activexcontrols":false,
   "ismobiledevice":false,
   "istablet":false,
   "issyndicationreader":false,
   "crawler":false,
   "isfake":false,
   "isanonymized":false,
   "ismodified":false,
   "cssversion":"3",
   "aolversion":"0",
   "device_name":"Windows Desktop",
   "device_maker":"unknown",
   "device_type":"Desktop",
   "device_pointing_method":"mouse",
   "device_code_name":"Windows Desktop",
   "device_brand_name":"unknown",
   "renderingengine_name":"Blink",
   "renderingengine_version":"unknown",
   "renderingengine_description":"a WebKit Fork by Google",
   "renderingengine_maker":"Google Inc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<?php
    function is_bot($user_agent) {
        return preg_match('/(abot|dbot|ebot|hbot|kbot|lbot|mbot|nbot|obot|pbot|rbot|sbot|tbot|vbot|ybot|zbot|bot\.|bot\/|_bot|\.bot|\/bot|\-bot|\:bot|\(bot|crawl|slurp|spider|seek|accoona|acoon|adressendeutschland|ah\-ha\.com|ahoy|altavista|ananzi|anthill|appie|arachnophilia|arale|araneo|aranha|architext|aretha|arks|asterias|atlocal|atn|atomz|augurfind|backrub|bannana_bot|baypup|bdfetch|big brother|biglotron|bjaaland|blackwidow|blaiz|blog|blo\.|bloodhound|boitho|booch|bradley|butterfly|calif|cassandra|ccubee|cfetch|charlotte|churl|cienciaficcion|cmc|collective|comagent|combine|computingsite|csci|curl|cusco|daumoa|deepindex|delorie|depspid|deweb|die blinde kuh|digger|ditto|dmoz|docomo|download express|dtaagent|dwcp|ebiness|ebingbong|e\-collector|ejupiter|emacs\-w3 search engine|esther|evliya celebi|ezresult|falcon|felix ide|ferret|fetchrover|fido|findlinks|fireball|fish search|fouineur|funnelweb|gazz|gcreep|genieknows|getterroboplus|geturl|glx|goforit|golem|grabber|grapnel|gralon|griffon|gromit|grub|gulliver|hamahakki|harvest|havindex|helix|heritrix|hku www octopus|homerweb|htdig|html index|html_analyzer|htmlgobble|hubater|hyper\-decontextualizer|ia_archiver|ibm_planetwide|ichiro|iconsurf|iltrovatore|image\.kapsi\.net|imagelock|incywincy|indexer|infobee|informant|ingrid|inktomisearch\.com|inspector web|intelliagent|internet shinchakubin|ip3000|iron33|israeli\-search|ivia|jack|jakarta|javabee|jetbot|jumpstation|katipo|kdd\-explorer|kilroy|knowledge|kototoi|kretrieve|labelgrabber|lachesis|larbin|legs|libwww|linkalarm|link validator|linkscan|lockon|lwp|lycos|magpie|mantraagent|mapoftheinternet|marvin\/|mattie|mediafox|mediapartners|mercator|merzscope|microsoft url control|minirank|miva|mj12|mnogosearch|moget|monster|moose|motor|multitext|muncher|muscatferret|mwd\.search|myweb|najdi|nameprotect|nationaldirectory|nazilla|ncsa beta|nec\-meshexplorer|nederland\.zoek|netcarta webmap engine|netmechanic|netresearchserver|netscoop|newscan\-online|nhse|nokia6682\/|nomad|noyona|nutch|nzexplorer|objectssearch|occam|omni|open text|openfind|openintelligencedata|orb search|osis\-project|pack rat|pageboy|pagebull|page_verifier|panscient|parasite|partnersite|patric|pear\.|pegasus|peregrinator|pgp key agent|phantom|phpdig|picosearch|piltdownman|pimptrain|pinpoint|pioneer|piranha|plumtreewebaccessor|pogodak|poirot|pompos|poppelsdorf|poppi|popular iconoclast|psycheclone|publisher|python|rambler|raven search|roach|road runner|roadhouse|robbie|robofox|robozilla|rules|salty|sbider|scooter|scoutjet|scrubby|search\.|searchprocess|semanticdiscovery|senrigan|sg\-scout|shai\'hulud|shark|shopwiki|sidewinder|sift|silk|simmany|site searcher|site valet|sitetech\-rover|skymob\.com|sleek|smartwit|sna\-|snappy|snooper|sohu|speedfind|sphere|sphider|spinner|spyder|steeler\/|suke|suntek|supersnooper|surfnomore|sven|sygol|szukacz|tach black widow|tarantula|templeton|\/teoma|t\-h\-u\-n\-d\-e\-r\-s\-t\-o\-n\-e|theophrastus|titan|titin|tkwww|toutatis|t\-rex|tutorgig|twiceler|twisted|ucsd|udmsearch|url check|updated|vagabondo|valkyrie|verticrawl|victoria|vision\-search|volcano|voyager\/|voyager\-hc|w3c_validator|w3m2|w3mir|walker|wallpaper|wanderer|wauuu|wavefire|web core|web hopper|web wombat|webbandit|webcatcher|webcopy|webfoot|weblayers|weblinker|weblog monitor|webmirror|webmonkey|webquest|webreaper|websitepulse|websnarf|webstolperer|webvac|webwalk|webwatch|webwombat|webzinger|wget|whizbang|whowhere|wild ferret|worldlight|wwwc|wwwster|xenu|xget|xift|xirq|yandex|yanga|yeti|yodao|zao\/|zippp|zyborg|\.\.\.\.)/i', $user_agent);
    }

    //example usage
    if (! is_bot($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) echo "it's a human hit! //do your code here";
?>
```

[Tell bots apart from human visitors for stats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717049/tell-bots-apart-from-human-visitors-for-stats)